# How to add live account to TFS team?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have a virtual environment running on azure, and have installed and setup TFS correctly.

However I would like to know how I can give access to my project by using a hotmail account, or for example invite someone to the team which does not have a user in the active directory? I hope this is possible! :)

Comment: I believe you can invite them, but they'll need to register into the AD anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using on-premise TFS hosted in Azure, you can't. User accounts are backed by AD/Windows security, plain and simple.

If you're using Team Services, you can use any email address you want and they can sign that email address up to be a Microsoft account, if it isn't already.